# Android disable viewpager swipe when touchimageview is zoomed

Tags: android, touchimageview

My app is doing a gallery which uses [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) and Viewpager. The problem is when the imageview is zoomed, it is hard to scroll the imageview to see the rest of the image, because the app seems doing swiping first How can it do. Is it possible to check if the imageview is already dragged to left or right edge, and if it is true then disable swipe of viewpager?

Comment: I have just completed a similar project and haven't experienced your issue. Are you using a custom `ViewPager`/`PagerAdapter`?

Comment: oh, my mistake. it works for both dragging the image and swiping the pages, but it is not smooth, looks like lagging. Finally only swipe is done. So I think how can I disable swiping when zoomed imageview not reaching the left & right edge. Sorry for misleading

Comment: That's strange as well. Maybe because the image is too large? What's its resolution?

Comment: Some of them with same problem is quite small, maybe 200x50

Comment: Your issue is weird. I can only suggest you to create a custom `ViewPager` and override its `onInterceptTouchEvent`'s `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`. `TouchImageView` has a method `isZoomed()`, use it to lock the swipe when it returns true.